# How to use sheet 2 data as reference data for sheet1s automaticallly sorting tables for a league

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to enter scores on sheet2 so that the players on the two tables on sheet1 are updated. The caveat is that I have a script running on sheet1 to automatically sort the tables (top one is most points and bottom one is highest win percentage)

I've got this far with chatgpt and a script it created for me but I cannot for the life of me work out how to get it to essentially always match the named players with their wins/draws/losses when the data changes with every added win/draw/loss.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TdcD43aeDaW_sSItltgzqL_km0UEibmb_zfE5REBc6c/edit?usp=sharing

The things I have tried seem to mess up when the script runs because the names are in a different order I imagine. I hope this makes sense as I'm not very literate in the terms used to describe what I'm trying to achieve.

Long story short I just want to add a win/draw/loss to sheet2 and have it apply to both tables in sheet1 but not mess up the data when it autosorts

I tried using vlookup but it didn't seem to work the way it should.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're struggling exactly. If you have problems when copying this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B7, sheet2!A2:H, 2, FALSE)
```

You should anchor the values:

```
=VLOOKUP(B7, sheet2!$A$2:$H, 2, FALSE)
```

You can use, instead of your script, a formula to grab the values, calculate the points and SORT according to that column. With this formula, you'd get the full green chart:

```
=SORT(FILTER({sheet2!A2:D17,INDEX(sheet2!B2:B17*3+sheet2!C2:C17*1+sheet2!D2:D17*-1)},sheet2!A2:A17<>""),5,0)
```

[image]

Comment: That's amazing thanks Martín, the formula seems a lot cleaner and works better than the script. I'll work out how to do the second table using this formula :)